# Select specific node properties

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm having some trouble selecting some specific XML data out of a document.
The underlying data is marketing events. There can be multiple events per document. Inside of each event are multiple attendees and registrants.
I started off using `SelectNodes()` inside of `foreach` loops and read it into a hash table before converting out to CSV.

For a single event this seemed to work fine, but for multiple events the rows were inconsistent, the eventid was out of sync from the other record data.
I'm now thinking of just exporting the whole XML into a CSV and letting an ETL tool take control from there.

There's a gap in my understanding here and wondered if anyone knew how to select multiple specific XML attributes into a CSV but it kept the sequence in order.

My PowerShell code:

```bsh
cls
[xml]$xml = Get-Content ("D:\sample.xml")

$dataTable  = @()
$eventNodes = $xml.SelectNodes('//event')
foreach ($event in $eventNodes) {
    $eventid    = $event.eventid
    $eventtitle = $event.eventtitle.InnerText               
    $eventtime  = $event.eventtime                           

    # get registrant data
    $registrantNodes = $xml.SelectNodes('//registrant')
    foreach ($registrant in $registrantNodes) {
        $firstname = $registrant.firstname.InnerText
        $lastname  = $registrant.lastname.InnerText
        $city      = $registrant.city.InnerText
        $state     = $registrant.state.InnerText    
        $country   = $registrant.country.InnerText
        $company   = $registrant.company.InnerText
        $workphone = $registrant.workphone.InnerText    
        $email     = $registrant.email.InnerText

        # get attendee data
        $attendeeNodes = $xml.SelectNodes('//attendee')
        foreach ($attendee in $attendeeNodes) {
            $attendedlive    = $attendee.attendedlive.InnerText
            $attendedarchive = $attendee.attendedarchive.InnerText

            # put all data into holding table
            $dataEntry = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                FirstName       = $firstname;
                LastName        = $lastname;
                City            = $city;
                State           = $state;
                Country         = $country;
                Company         = $company;
                WorkPhone       = $workphone;
                Email           = $email;
                AttendedLive    = $attendedlive;
                AttendedArchive = $attendedarchive;
                EventID         = $eventid;
                EventTitle      = $eventtitle;
                EventTime       = $eventtime;
                Orginization    = 'North America';
            }
            $dataTable += $dataEntry
        }
    }
}

# display holding table
$dataTable

$dataTable | Export-Csv -Force -Path "D:\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I uploaded a sample XML file [here](https://pastebin.com/6Jric3RF). The layout looks like this:

[image: XML layout]

Comment: Never load XML files this way. The correct way to load an XML file in PowerShell is `$xml = New-Object xml; $xml.Load($path)`. Doing it this way will properly auto-detect the XML file encoding. Using `Get-Content` will break the data when the file encoding is not matching `Get-Content`'s default. It's the equivalent of finger-crossing, which isn't smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that all your XPaths are absolute paths - they all start at the root of the document. When you query for `//registrant`, the XML document won't magically give you all the registrants that belong to what you happen to think of as the "current" event on this particular line of code. It will give you *all* the registrants for all events, because that's what you've asked for. Use relative navigation, i.e. XPaths that start with the current element (`.` in XPath) if you want relative results, like in this case.

Your secondary problem is that registrants and attendees are related to each other by an `eventuserid`. You can't simply query for any registrant, you must take that ID into account to pick the right one. Your code does not do that, luckily it's very simple in XPath.

You tertiary problem is that you look at the whole task top-down. Event - registrant - attendee. That's how your XML is structured, but *actually* you want one output line in your CSV per attendee, with some related data for that person. So it's sensible to do this bottom-up: attendee first, then the according registrant and event.

Consider this code:

```
cls

$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.Load("D:\sample.xml")

$allAttendees = $xml.SelectNodes('//attendee') | ForEach-Object {
    $attendee = $_
    $event = $attendee.SelectSingleNode('./ancestor::event[1]')
    $registrant = $event.SelectSingleNode("./registrants/registrant[eventuserid = '$($attendee.eventuserid)']")
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        FirstName       = $registrant.firstname
        LastName        = $registrant.lastname
        City            = $registrant.city
        State           = $registrant.state
        Country         = $registrant.country
        Company         = $registrant.company
        WorkPhone       = $registrant.workphone
        Email           = $registrant.email
        AttendedLive    = $attendee.attendedlive
        AttendedArchive = $attendee.attendedarchive
        EventID         = $event.eventid;
        EventTitle      = $event.eventtitle
        EventTime       = $event.eventtime
        Orginization    = 'North America';
    }
}

$allAttendees | Export-Csv -Force -Path "D:\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Notes

- All XPaths are invoked at a certain node and begin with `.` to refer to that node.
- All values you produce inside a script block in PowerShell and don't store in a variable become part of the return value of that script block. That's how the `ForEach-Object` body produces an array of objects without the need to add them to a temp variable. That's how the assignment to `$allAttendees` works above.
- Things to read about: XPath predicates and XPath axes and how string interpolation works in Powershell, in case the `"...$($attendee.eventuserid)..."` construct is unfamiliar to you.
- Using `.InnerText` explicitly is superfluous. Powershell will do that for you automatically.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, thank you so much for that very detailed reply and answer.

This was the first time I'd worked with XML reading of data and my code was based on scraps from blog posts.
The top down logic problem was indeed something that annoyed me, I thought that the XML would read sequential and that loading as a row would 'handle' the sequence.
And thanks also for the tips on XPath, I'll go and do a bit of reading now as I hadn't heard of axes or predicates.
The code you posted makes total sense now. Very best wishes and thanks again for helping me tackle the knowledge gaps I had.

Comment: You're very welcome. Thanks for the feedback. There are XML APIs that read the document sequentially, but the one that gets used by Powershell by default doesn't do that. It reads the whole thing into one big tree into RAM and you can navigate that tree along the branches with XPath. This method is fine for XML files that easily fit into RAM - when you get to GB-sized XML files, the sequential APIs start to become useful. I found this graphical representation of axes helpful: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/macros/xslt/xpath-axes-and-their-shortcuts